# алгоритм вывода связанных значений из трех таблиц mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, запрос, select

### Есть задача, в общем виде: имеются таблицы с данными (упрощенно)

- таблица компонентов: `ид, параметр1, параметр2, параметр3, значение, количество`
- таблица соответствия параметра1: `ид, имя параметра, булево_значение (используем ли еще параметры для разбора)` могут быть десятки строк
- таблица соответствия параметра2: `ид, имя параметра` могут быть десятки/сотни строк
- таблица соответствия параметра3: `ид, имя параметра` могут быть сотни/тысячи строк
- pivot(если её можно так назвать) таблица параметров: `ид, ид_параметр1, ид_параметр2, ид_параметр3`
- таблица наименований: `ид, ид_pivot_элемента, имя`

Необходимо при выводе значений из таблицы компонентов выводить имя из таблицы наименований. Принцип построения таблицы наименований такой:

- Если по имени мы нашли параметр1 в таблице соответствий параметра1, то проверяем булево_значение, если `true` тогда учитываем значения параметра2 и параметра3 (если `false` то ничего не делается)
- Далее поулчаем ид сопоставления параметра2 и параметра3, ищем полный набор в таблице pivot, если находим - то в дополнении к данным из таблицы компонентов выводим имя из таблицы наименований.

На сколько вообще правильно такое построение логики?
Правильно ли постоянно делать SELECT из базы для проверки значений, или лучше заранее сделать массив со всем значениями и проверять через массив (т.к. это будет на php - не сильно сожрет память на массиве в несколько 2-4 столбца на тысяч значений)?
Заранее благодарен за помощь, и прошу конструктивную критику, а не просто - "так не делают"

Comment: Вопрос в том, что такое "вывод значений из таблицы". Сколько значений вы получаете из БД за один запуск скрипта. Заполнять массивы-справочники данными при каждом запуске скрипта обычно дорого (если конечно он не постоянно запущен и периодически без обновления справочников что то ищет в них). И откуда собственно поступают данные - если все из БД - то любые данные из БД всегда можно получить за один вызов одного единственного запроса, что гораздо быстрее использования любых массивов. А если приходится "постоянно делать select" видимо не правильно используются возможности SQL

Comment: Согласен, возможно изначально неправильно строю логику. Вообще все происходит в 2 этапа. 1. - это загрузка из csv значений для таблицы  компонентов. 2. - это вывод выборки по таблице компонентов. В общем - частота вызова выборки маленькая, разы в час. импорта еще реже. Сейчас конечный вывод до сотни строк. "видимо не правильно используются возможности SQL" каюсь в sql не силен. Думал о вариантах JOIN'ов, но не хотелось усложнять

Comment: А что вы все таки оптимизируете. загрузку из csv или выдачу данных. я так понимаю это разные задачи, раз они происходят с разной регулярностью. А загрузке из csv массивы может и были бы полезны, вы же кучу данных переводите из имен в ID небось. А при выдаче данных только join, они конечно усложняют сам запрос, зато логики в php остается только сделать цикл и выдать на страницу

Comment: Вообще нужно и то и то даже не оптимизировать, а сразу по-правильному сделать. при импорте из csv я как раз импортирую имена, не перевожу в ид. но, в тоже время проверяю есть-ли такие имена в соответствиях, если нет - то пользователь должен внести руками соответствия + еще доп поля внести. Понимаю что может быть нужно было сделать импорт с преобразованием имен в ид, но возможен вариант, что пользователю понадобится что-то исправить в таблице компонентов с просто именами это быстрее и понятнее(для меня) чем через ид это делать. Или нет?